# In Python, how to parse a datetime from a string which also contains other words

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, python-dateutil

I'm familiar with [dateutil.parser](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) which allows one to parse a string representing a time into a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object. What I would like to do, however, is to 'search' for such a 'time string' within a larger string representing an interval of time. For example:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import dateutil.parser
import parse

start = dateutil.parser.parse("5 Nov 2016 15:00")
end = start + timedelta(hours=1)

string = "from {start} till {end}".format(start=start, end=end)

start_pattern = "from {:tg}"
result = parse.search(start_pattern, string)
```

I'd like to recover the `start` and `end` as `datetime` objects based on the fact that they follow the words "from" and "till", respectively.

Here I have tried to use the [parse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) module, but the format specifier `:tg` (for global time syntax) doesn't seem to work on `datetime`'s default string representation, nor do the other available ones look similar to the one in `string`.

What would be a simple and elegant way to parse back the `start` and `end` in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `re` package could help you in this case; just make regular expressions for the strings you want to match, and use them to extract the date part.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do it using a regular expression:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import dateutil.parser
import re

start = dateutil.parser.parse("5 Nov 2016 15:00")
end = start + timedelta(hours=1)

string = "from {start} till {end}".format(start=start, end=end)

pattern = '(?:\s*from\s*)' + '(?P<start>.+)' + '(?:\s*till\s*)' + '(?P<end>.+)' + '(?:\s*)'

groups = re.match(pattern, string).groupdict()

parsed_start = dateutil.parser.parse(groups['start'])
parsed_end = dateutil.parser.parse(groups['end'])

assert parsed_start == start
assert parsed_end == end
```